# Change password daily on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, login

Is it possible to provide for a user account a list of passwords to windows 7. The list contains one password for each day. Then when the user logs into windows up the password for today is looked up?

usecase is of private nature: Kids can get current password after finishing homework...

Comment: I know of no way of changing a password based on a list.  What you could do is disable the account, requiring your intervention, each day.  But Windows offers more features to Child accounts, you can set active times, and time restrictions.  Address the problem differently, allow x hours daily, but the time could be used before homework (but that’s a human problem)

Comment: So, access after a given time...ie 6pm or only between 6 and 7... if that is possible..

Answer (score 0):

You could schedule a job to use the net user command to disable the account every day at a certain time. And enable it when the homework is done.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/251394/how-to-use-the-net-user-command

Comment: I did not want to go into these details really (maybe should just not have mentioned my usecase...), but with this list on my desk i can just be busy on my own until they go to visit me and fetch their password.